# How to use Lucene for getting tags for tagcloud?

Tags: java, tags, lucene

I'm a Lucene newbie and I have it working where I can create an index from a column of a database table storing tags, and search this index for a particular tag and display the results and their scores. I'm looking at this as an alternative to a MySQL fulltext index which I've heard mixed comments about.

But, what I want is to get from the most popular tags in the index along with their counts and then use this data to create a tagcloud.

Does anyone know if and how Lucene can be queried to get the most popular tags in an index and their counts at all?

Thanks

Mr Morgan.

Answer (score 3):

very detailed [tutorial](http://www.discursive.com/books/cjcook/reference/searching-filtering-sect-freq-terms.html)

basically you get all the terms from the document, the get the term frequency

Comment: Can u mark the answer as accepted, it will ensure you get responses to other questions you ask

Comment: Don't provide link-only answers. Please add a quick summary too.